# touch pad not working lenovo ideapad 320

Tags: ideapad

I need help on my new Lenovo ideapad320 laptop devices not working are USB Type-C and Touch Pad.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release have you installed?

Comment: Please add more information: are there any errors? Do they work somewhere else? Do you have any external devices?

Comment: I have also facing the same issue.. Today only i got my new ideapad 320 and I have install ubuntu 16 on it.. The touch pad is not working on it .