# Touchpad/Bluetooth mouse not working un Lenovo Yoga 720-15IKB in Ubuntu 16.04, Kernel 4.13

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, bluetooth

I succesfully installed my dualboot Ubuntu (the main OS is W10) today after updating my bios on my laptop. My laptop is a Lenovo Yoga 720-15IKB.

I discovered that my touchpad isn't working and neither is my bluetooth mouse (Microsoft Designer). I was running Kernel 4.10. The system could find my mouse at first, try to connect to it and then give an error that it failed to set the connection up.

I decided to give a newer kernel a try and upgraded my kernel to 4.13 and I'm running that succesfully now. The touchpad is still not working and neither is the bluetooth mouse.

At least my touch screen is working properly, but I'd really like to have the touchpad and bluetooth working as well as I can't be arsed carrying a wired mouse with me everywhere...

I tried running inxi and here's the pastebin from that:
https://pastebin.com/DWDASqnQ

Any tips on what I should try to fix it?

Edit: The Kernel found in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948439/touchpad-not-detected-on-lenovo-ideapad-320-with-kubuntu-17-04) did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Touchpad not detected on Lenovo Ideapad 320 with Kubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948439/touchpad-not-detected-on-lenovo-ideapad-320-with-kubuntu-17-04)

Comment: The touchpad issue will be fixed soon in a new kernel upgrade of native Ubuntu kernels.

Comment: The bluetooth issue is another issue for another question.

Comment: The Kernel module did not fix it for me. Secure Boot was disabled as well.

Comment: The module won't work with the 4.13 anyway. There is a link to a kernel with the fix.

Comment: I installed the Kernel with the fix, still not working unfortunately. :(

Comment: If you are sure that you booted with that kernel, then it is another issue.

Comment: Atleast typing "uname -r" in Terminal returns with "4.12.0-11-generic". I'm a newbie with Ubuntu though, so I can't guarantee that I installed the Kernel right... Basically I just typed "sudo dpkg -i [.deb file path here]" for all 4 files, then updated grub and restarted my laptop, I guess that's how it's done?

Comment: It looks correct. You can file another bug report to Launchpad. You need to boot with the official kernel and run `ubuntu-bug linux`.

Comment: About the Bluetooth issue, there seems to be a general problem with kernel 4.13: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+kernel+4.13+bluetooth+not+working&t=canonical&ia=web

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and it does not work for me anymore. Reverting to an older kernel is a work-around for now.

Answer (score 0):

I also managed to install Ubuntu on the yoga 720 and wrote a [thorough install guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/963767/34298).

To get the touchpad running you have to install a newer kernel, at least the kernel 4.14-rc5 (4.14 will be released in November 2017).

I installed the latest kernel with [this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/963779/34298) and got the touchpad running, but then at first the networking will be broken due to a bug in the apparmor settings, you can fix this by

```
sudo apt install apparmour-utils
sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient
```

(source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397708)